# Scala: Can't pass an Array to a function where Seq or Iterable is expected

Tags: scala, generics, scala-collections

I was trying to write a generic function that takes a type parameter T which is a subset of Seq[String], below is the sample example

```
def test[T <:Seq[String]](c:T):T = {
c
}
```

I defined a variable which is Array[String]

```
val b = Array("test")
```

Now I was expecting this to work, however, I get an error as below

```
scala> test(b)
       ^
       error: inferred type arguments [Array[String]] do not conform to method test's type parameter bounds [T <: Seq[String]]
            ^
       error: type mismatch;
        found   : Array[String]
        required: T
```

I tried defining T as a subset of Iterable[String], but that also doesn't work.

I understand that Array in Scala is not a Seq, but I was hoping it to be implicitly converted to
WrappedArray and this function to still work. Can someone help me what is wrong with this?

Comment: It's because `Array` comes from Java land and sits outside of the standard Scala collections. It can be done but it's not trivial and is somewhat dependent of which version of Scala you're running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand that Array in Scala is not a Seq, but I was hoping it to be implicitly converted to WrappedArray and this function to still work. Can someone help me what is wrong with this?

What's wrong with this is this:

> I was hoping it to be implicitly converted to WrappedArray

You hoping it doesn't make it true. Only what's written in the [*Scala Language Specification*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/) is true.

[Section 3.2.6 *Parameterized Types*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#parameterized-types) says that "The parameterized type is well-formed if each actual type parameter *conforms to its bounds*".

And [Section 3.5.2 *Conformance*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#conformance) defines what "conforms" means, and it doesn't mention implicit conversion anywhere.

Therefore, `Array[String]` does not *conform* to `Seq[String]` and is thus not a valid actual type argument for the formal type parameter `T`.

Answer (score 3):

To return the same collection type as received, including `Array`, you have to bring some special type classes into play.

Here's one (not particularly great) example. (Scala 2.13.x)

```
import scala.collection.Factory
import scala.collection.generic.IsIterable

def test[CC[_]](c:CC[String]
               )(implicit isit: IsIterable[CC[String]] {type A = String}
                        , fac : Factory[String,CC[String]]
                ): CC[String] =
  isit(c).map(_.reverse).to(fac)

test(Array("abc"))           //res0: Array[String] = Array(cba)
test(Vector("Go","Jo"))      //res1: Vector[String] = Vector(oG, oJ)
test(List("my","dad","Bob")) //res2: List[String] = List(ym, dad, boB)
```